# SQL Server - Create an identifying relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, foreign-keys, primary-key, foreign-key-relationship

I'm currently designing a database to be implemented in SQL Server. I created the following tables without problem:

```
CREATE TABLE [Client] (
  [ClientId] INT NOT NULL,
  [Name] VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  [IsEnabled] BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  CONSTRAINT PK_TCASystem PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (
ClientId
 )
);

 CREATE TABLE [Configuration] (
  [ConfigId] INT NOT NULL,
  [ClientId] INT NOT NULL,
  [Name] VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT PK_Configuration PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (
    ConfigId, ClientId
  ),
  CONSTRAINT "FK_SystemConfiguration" FOREIGN KEY 
  (
    ClientId
  ) REFERENCES [Client] (
    ClientId
  )
 );
```

However, when I tried to add this one:

```
CREATE TABLE [Mail] (
   [MailId] INT NOT NULL,
   [ConfigId] INT NOT NULL,
   [Recipient] VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
   [Sender] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   [Subject] VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
   [Message] TEXT NULL,

   CONSTRAINT PK_Mail PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (
    MailId, ConfigId
   ),
   CONSTRAINT "FK_ConfigurationMail" FOREIGN KEY 
   (
        ConfigId
   ) REFERENCES [Configuration] (
        ConfigId
   )
);
```

I got an error saying that `There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'Configuration' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK_ConfigurationMail'`. I believe this is because the constraint is trying to reference `ConfigId`, only one half of the composite key, and for this to work I'd need to reference the `ClientId` too, is that correct?

But my problem is that I first did the design for this database in MYSQL Workbench, and there I indicated that `Configuration` and `Mail`, as well as `Client and Configuration`, have a 1:n identifying relationship (because a `Mail` instance cannot be created if there isn't a `Configuration` instance first, and at the same time a `Configuration` instance cannot exist without having being assigned to a `Client` first), and as such it created the composite keys for `Configuration` and `Mail`. You can see a picture of that [here](https://i.imgur.com/4LzYNtR).

So my question is, how can I translate this identifying relationship to SQL Server? Or is that not possible?

**EDIT**: As suggested I will remove the composite keys from the `Configuration` table, albeit my question still stands: *If I have a 1:n identifying relationship where one of the tables involved uses composite keys, how can I display this on SQL Server?* Or is such a case never supposed to happen?

**2ND EDIT**: To anyone who might come across this question, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2814810/1499934) post is well worth a read. Cleared up all my confusion in the matter.

Comment: Let me see if I understand. A configuration instance can't exist without **first** being assigned to a client??

Comment: That's right. Changed the wording in case it was too ambigous.

Comment: I still read it the same way. It doesn't really make much sense to me, how is it possibly that a configuration instance can't exists without first being assigned to a client?

Comment: Does it make sense to have multiple identical ConfigIds? That is allowed at the moment.

Comment: @usr Identical? It should be that a Client can have more than one Configuration... but where does it say that they could be identical?

Comment: Because logically if you want to assign a configuration instance to a client, then that configuration instance **should** exist first, not the other way around

Comment: Just insert (1, 1) and (1, 2). Two identical ConfigIds.

Comment: Also, your design should have a `Client` table (with `ClientId` alone being the primary key), a `Configuration` table (with `ConfigurationId` alone being the primary key), **and** a `ClientConfiguration` table that relates them (with `ClientId, ConfigurationId` as the composite primary key)

Comment: @Lamak But a configuration can only belong to one client at a time, shouldn't it remain as a 1:n relationship then? Although what you mentioned about Configuration needing to exist before a Client makes sense, I'll have to check that with my manager.

Comment: @AnaAmeer It's still a good idea to have those on a different table in the case of sometime in the future changing that restriction. That also makes it not necessary to update the `client` table with the `Configuration` information, and have those concepts separated

Comment: Your model is fine, just remove the composite keys. Having a `ClientConfiguration` would only be needed if you need the same configuration for multiple clients.

Comment: Thank you both for the suggestions, but my original question remains unsolved. Or is a case like this not intended to ever happen?

Comment: You are currently saying that the `Configuration` table could have more than one identical value for `ConfigurationId` (since it has a composite primary key). In SQL Server (and it should be this way in every RBDMS, not sure why MySQL allows it), you can't reference a part of a primary key, it needs to reference the whole primary key

Comment: @AnaAmeer Check my solution. Foreign key must reference PK or unique index. So add this between create table [Configuration] and [Mail]. It is working in sql fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Foreign key must reference PK (the entire PK, not portion of PK) or unique index. So add this between create table [Configuration] and [Mail].

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [UX_Configuration] ON [Configuration] 
   (
       [ConfigId] ASC
   )

Check out at sql fiddle for the whole working script: 
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8877f

Comment: After everyone's suggestions I ended up changing the design of the table, but thank you for the answer!