# Which database relationship to use?

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I am totally new to the MySQL. 
There are 5 different types of relationships in MySQL:

```
1:1 Non-identifying 
1:n Non-identifying 
1:1 Identifying 
1:n Identifying
n:m Identifying
```

how to know which one to select, and what is the difference between identifying and non-identifying.

Thanks you...

Comment: It depends on the problem/domain being modeled. Might want to start with a SQL/RDBMS/RA book.. and some paper to 'scratch model ideas on'. As far as the second question, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2814469/still-confused-about-identifying-vs-non-identifying-relationships

Comment: ... also Wikipedia has an article about identifying vs non-identifying.

Comment: <snide-opinion>"Identifying" is a term invented by a professor with nothing better to do.</snide-opinion>  I've been working with databases for 25 years, and have not encountered that term until now.

Comment: You can go a long way by understanding only two patterns:  1:n is implemented a link in one table to the other table.  n:m is implemented by an extra table with ids linking to the existing 2 tables.