# Relationships between table levels and foreign keys

Tags: database-design, relational-database

I need help with the following structure in my database.

These are the tables

1. PriceList
2. OptionalGroup
3. ProductGroup
4. Product

Now I need to structure this things up, lets begin from the last table article.

The article belongs to a product, then the product belongs to a productgroup, then the productgroup belongs to an OptionalGroup, and the OptionalGroup belongs to a PriceList.

And today the relationship looks like this.

- Table: PriceList
- Table: OptionalGroup has ForeignKey to PriceListId
- Table: ProductGroup has ForeignKey to OptionalGroup
- Table: Product has ForeignKey to ProductGroup

Sample data:

```
>  Pricelist: 81
   >  OptionalGroup: Shoes
       > ProductGroup: Shoelace
       >   Product: Shoelace 1
       >   Product: Shoelace 2
```

How should I design this?

In this way, to get a product I need to now pricelist, optionalgroup, productgroup then I can get the product. Because pricelist has their own OptionalGroup and it could also have the same optionalgroup name.

Comment: Are all the levels in that hierarchy always required?

Comment: @wp91 ..how should i design this? is the question ;) just read my text.

Comment: What's the application? An inventory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How should I design this?

You already did ;) Your data model seems appropriate to what you described as your requirements.

There are some possible variations without radically changing the basic idea though. For example...

[image]

...uses [identifying](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13295288/533120) relationships to "migrate" the parent PKs to children, so you can (for example) get the `PriceListId` directly from the `Product` table, without JOINing with `ProductGroup` and `OptionalGroup` tables, but at the price of "fatter" child FKs.

Whether the design with non-identifying relationships is better than the design shown here is a matter of the engineering tradeoff. Both have pros and cons and it is your task to pick one with more pros and less cons *for your particular case*.

---

Also, in case there are no `(other fields)` in the `PriceList` table, and you can never have an empty price list (or simply don't make a distinction between empty and non-existent price list), you can omit that table entirely.

Answer (score 0):

This design will do,

```
table name PriceList
ProductID--> PK
Price
table name OptionalGroup
GroupID--> PK
ProductID--> FK
GroupName
table name ProductGroup
ProductGroupID--> PK
ProductGroupName
GroupID--> FK
table name Product
ProductName
ProductGroupID-->FK
```