# MySQL: Foreign Keys

Tags: mysql, indexing

Sorry if this is already answered somewhere, but how do i create a foreign key that is not always present.

Example: I have a table called invoice_payments with the INT columns 'type' and 'cc_gateway'.  I also have a 2nd table called invoice_cc_gateway.  Since I can accept multiple payment types (cash, cc payments online) i store the type of payment in type (0=cash, 1=cc gateway), and when it is a payment from the gateway, I want to link to that specific item.

Now my problem is, I know how to link the two tables together if the key always exists, but what if the key won't always be present.  If we have a cash payment, I set cc_gateway to 0, since it does not relate.

In the past I just created a dummy row for 0 inside cc_gateway so that my keys always match, but there must be a more correct way to do this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Rephrased answer**

Sorry, I was a bit quick before, of course you can have a foreign key in the Gateway-table that references the Items paid via gateway, but the opposite can not be true (ie a key in the Item table linking to the Gateway table)

If the key will not always be present it cannot be a foreign key constraint (references ), but instead you will have to join the gateway table when that value is present.

**Example**

```
select * from invoice_payments inv
left join invoice_cc_gateway gw
on inv.paymentId = gw.paymentId
where paymentType = 1
union
select * from invoice_payments
where paymentType = 0
```

Comment: Well I basically only care so that my diagram reflects this link between the two, but if I should not assign anything key wise, I will not worry.  Thank you.

Comment: I'm more concerned so that in a year if I go look at my EER Diagram, generated off the table, it reflects the relationships for me.  I know how to do the selects.  Thank you though

Comment: actually, i found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/762937/whats-the-difference-between-identifying-and-non-identifying-relationships which it appears what i want is a non-identifying-relationship.  Thank again!

Comment: Take a look at my new answer, I think that could clarify it a bit :)

Comment: Problem is, gateway may not always be referencing a item's paid row.  gateway can have many types of transactions, most commonly if a transaction failed.  I store these so i can detect common fraud practices.  Because of this, technically the payments received table relates to the gateway table (but not in all cases).  This happens a lot, and again, its basically so my diagrams can show others (or me a year from now) the relationship.  Inserting an empty row of 0 always did the trick so i can keep my indexed, but just figured that is a messy way of doing it.

Thanks again though =)