# MySQL DB Design Questions

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, database-design, foreign-keys

I have some fundamental DB design questions, and I wanted to get them cleared up before I go through and draw out all of the DB relations.

**Question 1**

I have two tables, where the first will contain 1 instance of the second.  I'll be using entity framework, and would like to be access `table1` from `table2`, and `table2` from `table1`.

My idea was to have a foreign key from `table1` to `table2`, and another from `table2` to `table1`.  Adding the link from `table1` to `table2` seems to work.  However, when I attempt to add the second link (from `table2` to `table1`), MySQL Workbench adds two links instead of one.  I'm thinking I'm doing something wrong since it's my understanding it should only add one link.  Is my design wrong, or should I just delete the second link that is being added?

[image: mysql workbench diagram]

**Question 2**

Next, I'm trying to implement a join table.  An instance of `table1` can have many instances of `table2` and vice-versa, so the join table seems to be the necessary structure to accomplish this.  MySQL allows me to create either an `Identifying Relationship` or a `Non-Identifying Relationship`, and I'm unsure of which to use.  Any ideas?

[image]

If more clarification is needed, please let me know.

Comment: what are you trying to model - furniture ?

Comment: The two images are of two different sets of tables.  In the first case I'm attempting to model a `word` that can have a single `image` associated to it, and a single `image` can belong to many `word`s.  In the second instance, a `user` can have many `word`s, and a `word` can belong to many `user`s.

Comment: About your second question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/762937/whats-the-difference-between-identifying-and-non-identifying-relationships

Comment: The first question, based on your comment, seems to need a simple `1:n` relationship. You only need one FK constraint: table `ìmage(image_id PK, ...)` and table `word(word_id PK, image_id, FOREIGN KEY (image_id) REFERENCES image(image_id))`

Comment: @ypercube you're saying a 1 image:n word relationship?  Would that be a regular end on the image and a fork end on the word pictorially?

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by [ypercube](https://stackoverflow.com/users/344949/ypercube) and [JesseB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/435460/jesseb) I think all you need is a 1..n relationship.

With Entity Framework 4.1 (and POCO Code First) all you need is a map that declares this relationship, like

```
this.HasRequired(t => t.Image)
  .WithMany(t => t.Words)
  .HasForeignKey(d => d.ImageId);
```

Please, find here a complete and working code. If launched it will create a database with all the needed foreign keys. You will see that tho sole foreign key you'd need is `image_id` in `words` table. Entity Framework is able to inject a collection of `Word`s into any `Image` object, without relying on any additional foreign key.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using WordAndImages.Entities;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration;

namespace WordAndImages
{

    public class Word
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ImageId { get; set; }
        public virtual Image Image { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    public class Image
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Word> Words { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public Image()
        {
            Words = new List<Word>();
        }
    }


    public class Context : DbContext
    {
        static Context()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<Context>(null);
        }

        public DbSet<Word> Words { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Image> Images { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new WordsMap());
        }
    }

    public class WordsMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Word>
    {
        public WordsMap()
        {
            this.HasRequired(t => t.Image)
              .WithMany(t => t.Words)
              .HasForeignKey(d => d.ImageId);
        }
    }


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            #region Saving a Word with an Image

            var context = new Context();
            context.Database.Delete();
            context.Database.CreateIfNotExists();

            var word = new Word();
            word.Value = "I'm a word";

            var image = new Image();
            image.Value = "I'm an image";

            word.Image = image;

            context.Words.Add(word);
            context.SaveChanges();
            #endregion

            #region Accessing an Image from a Word and viceversa

            var context2 = new Context();

            var recovered_word = context2.Words.Where(w => w.Value == "I'm a word").FirstOrDefault();
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("I'm the word '{0}' and my image is '{1}'", word.Value, word.Image.Value));

            var recovered_image = context2.Images.Where(w => w.Value == "I'm an image").FirstOrDefault();
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("I'm the image '{0}' and one of my images is '{1}'", recovered_image.Value, recovered_image.Words.First().Value));

            Console.ReadLine();
            #endregion
        }
    }
}
```

For a `many-to-many` relationship, just use a map like

```
this.HasMany(a => a.Words)
  .WithMany(z => z.Images)
  .Map(m =>
  m.ToTable("Images_Words").MapLeftKey("Word_id").MapRightKey("Image_id"));
```

and modify your classes as follow

```
public class Word
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Image> Images { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public Word()
    {
        Images = new List<Image>();
    }
}

public class Image
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Word> Words { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public Image()
    {
        Words = new List<Word>();
    }
}
```

If not working with legacy databases, I like designing domain objects first, and let the ORM create tables and foreign keys.

In the case you'd prefere beginning from database, take into consideration the Extension Entity Framework Power Tools CTP1, which you can download from Extension Manager: it's able to produce POCO classes from a database.