# Which is the child table in a Identifying or Non-Identifying Relationship?

Tags: mysql

In the context of identifying and non-identifying relationships between tables, MySQL's documentation refers a lot to the tables as parent and child tables.

How do you determine which table is the parent table and which table is the child table?

Answer (score 10):

A child table (A.K.A. [weak entity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_entity)) is a table whose primary key attributes ***depend*** on another table, thus the child table is *identified* or *partially identified* by rows in the table it depends on (parent). Rows in a child table cannot exist without a corresponding row in its parent table.

To illustrate, let's take a simple and completely relevant example we are all familiar with: *Parents and children in the context of family*. We can model out this relationship with tables like so:

[image: Parent to Child Identifying Relationship]

In the model above, each row in the `Parents` table is ***uniquely identified*** by an `SSN`. The `SSN` is an intrinsic and unique attribute to each parent, thus it is a standalone or "strong" entity because it does not rely on another table to define its identity.

Children however, *require* a parent in order to exist (`Parent_SSN` ***must*** reference to an existing `SSN` in the `Parents` table).

Notice the composite primary key (`Parent_SSN, Name`) in the `Children` table. This means that children are ***uniquely identified*** by the *combination* of `Parent_SSN` **and** `Name`. You cannot query for an individual child based only on the `Name` field because multiple parents may have children with the same name. Likewise, you cannot query for an individual child based only on the `Parent_SSN` field because one parent may have many children. Taking that into consideration, children are partially identified by their parent, hence ***identifying*** relationship.

But can't children be uniquely identified by an SSN as well? Why yes, certainly. Let's go ahead and adjust our model to include that:

[image: Parent to Child Non-Identifying Relationship]

In this version of the model, notice we have introduced the `SSN` field for `Children`. The **unique identity** of children is now defined by their own intrinsic and unique `SSN`. Their identity **no longer depends** on the `Parents` table. Although the `Parent_SSN` field still references the `SSN` of the `Parents` table, it has no part in the *unique identity* of the child, thus parents have a ***non-identifying*** relationship to their children, and both tables can now be considered "strong" standalone entities.

As an aside, this version of the model has a few advantages over the first:

- One parent may now have two or more children with the same name, whereas the [entity integrity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_integrity) constraint in the previous model would not allow for this.
- You can allow the `Parent_SSN` field to contain `NULL` to account for the event that you have data about the child, but do not know who his/her parent is.

In both of the above models, the `Parents` table is considered to be the parent table of the `Children` table. However, in **non-identifying** relationships like in the second model, `Parents` is only a parent table in the context of the foreign key `Parent_SSN` because `Parent_SSN` *references/depends* on `SSN` in the `Parents` table, but *does not* have any part in defining the actual identity of children.

To illustrate why context is important when deciding which tables are parent/child tables, consider the following example involving a circular dependency:

[image: Employee Department Relationships]

In this example, employees and departments are uniquely identified by their own attributes and do not derive any part of their identity from other tables.

Here, we have two non-identifying relationships: an employee works for a department (`DeptNo` in the `Employee` table), and a department is managed by an employee (`ManagerSSN` in the `Department` table). Which one is the parent table? ...Child table?

It depends on context — which foreign key relationship are you talking about? The Department table would be considered the parent table in the context of `DeptNo` in the `Employee` table because `DeptNo` is *referencing/dependent* on the `Department` table.

However, the Employee table would be considered the parent table in the context of `ManagerSSN` in the `Department` table because `ManagerSSN` is *referencing/dependent* on the `Employee` table.

Answer (score 0):

There is no strict rule that will determine the role of a table in a relationship. In fact, that's the beauty and innovation of the relational model: no hierarchies.

Usually, if there is a hard dependency from certain table to another, the child or parent role are determined by semantics of the tables. Example: in a `order`, `order_details` relations, it's pretty obvious that `order` is the parent and `order_details` is the child.

In other cases, it's not clear what role a relation plays in a relationship. Example: `orders` and `customers` relation. If you perform a query to get all `orders` belonging to a certain `customer` then the parent might be `customers` and `orders` are children. But you can also do a query to get all shipment information (stored in `customers` relation) for a specific `order`, and in this case, you might argue that `order` is the parent while `customers` is the child in this query.

As I said before, when relational model was invented in late 70's, one of its main benefits over one of the reigning paradigm (hierarchical data model) was the ability of look for related data regardless of their dependency.

Comment: How about `person` `country` relationship? I would guess person is the parent table here. In this relationship would be a list of people and a list of countries. Each person is required to have a country (identifying relationship) however in the MySQL docs it says `An identifying relationship is one where the child table cannot be uniquely identified without its parent.` so that means the parent table would be `country` and child table is `person` which is completely opposite of what I would have expected...

Comment: @Jackobud: not necessarily. It depends on what you are looking for (your query). In that context `one where the child table cannot be uniquely identified without its parent`) neither `country` nor `person` tables are child in the relationship. In that case MySQL's doc is referring to a full dependency: i.e. `order_details` can't exist without their corresponding `orders`.

Comment: Hmmm, so is my example a identifying or non-identifying relationship?

Comment: Also, in your answer you make it sound like determining which table is parent/child only happens when you make queries on the tables, but when you design a database schema, you create these relationships between tables where one has to be a child and one has to be the parent, right?

Answer (score 0):

A great definition is proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/762994/1446005):

> An identifying relationship is when the existence of a row in a child
>   table depends on a row in a parent table. (...) Formally, the "right"
>   way to do this is to make the foreign key *[i.e. the parent's primary key]* part of
>   the child's primary key.