# Confused with MySQL Identifying vs Non-identifying relationships

Tags: mysql, sql, schema

I am designing a database schema for a location database. I am using MySQL Workbench 5.2.40 to create the following diagram. I'm presently confused as to the use of identifying vs non-identifying relationships.

Here's my schema diagram:

[image: schema diagram]

After reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762937/whats-the-difference-between-identifying-and-non-identifying-relationships) and other related questions here in SO, I was thinking I should use *identifying* relationships for those attributes that belong to the object itself (e.g. Locations have PhoneNumbers). But after I added a relationship between **Locations** and **OperatingHours**, I was surprised that it added the primary key of **CostRange**.

Is my use of identifying and/or non-identifying relationships wrong? If so, can you please give suggestions.

*Note: I am aware that there are more things that need to be changed in my schema. You may comment on the other aspects of the design but please let us focus first on the issues of my foreign keys in order for us not to get off-topic.*

Comment: identifying means, the PK of the parent table becomes the FK & part of PK in the child table.

Comment: So, maybe I should use _non-identifying_ then.