# visual paradigm identifying relationship

Tags: visual-paradigm

What does this checkbox mean? When I click it the foreign_key line representation becomes solid instead of dashed.
When I click it I also look the 'Sync to association' dropdown. What is this doing?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The following post explained the differences between the identifying and non-identifying relationships. 
[What's the difference between identifying and non-identifying relationships?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762937/whats-the-difference-between-identifying-and-non-identifying-relationships)

In the ERD solid connector is use to representing the identifying relationship, where the dotted connector is for representing the non-identifying relationship.

And the "Sync. to association" option is for the ERD and class model synchronization feature in Visual Paradigm. In Visual Paradigm you can have your ER model mapped with your class model (i.e. entity map to class, column map to attribute, and relationship in ERD map to association in class model), and you can generate hibernate out of it. By turning off the "Sync. to association" then that relationship will not be converted into association when you synchronize this ER model into class model. Details about the synchronization can be found at http://www.visual-paradigm.com/product/vpuml/features/dbobjectpersistence.jsp#syncorm