# Workbench creates unnecessary primary keys with identifying relationship

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Im currently trying to develop a schema for MySQL with the Workbench application and came across the the problem, seen in the following image:

[image]

My model shall have the properties:

There exist many areas (for example buildings on a certain terrain). For those areas exist maps for each floor. On each map can be placed several viewpoints.

So the relations are clearly:
1 area can have n maps.
1 map can have n viewpoints.

I drew them into the image. But why does Workbench insert map_id and area_id into viewpoint, although map_id would be enough? Isnt it kind of duplicate?

And an other question: Is it correct, that these relationships are identifying? I thought it would be that way, because a map can not exist without an area and a viewpoint not without a map.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please do not ask two different questions in a single Stackoverflow question. Open SO questions for each of them.

For the relationship: I'm not sure why area_id was inserted. Maybe that's because both map_id and area_id are in the PK. However, you should be able to remove area_id if you don't need it in the FK.

Re identifying relationships: that's a different matter. The requirement that a map can only exist if an area exists etc. is modelled by the ordinality of the relationship (which is what you get with a 1:n mandatory relationship). For identifying relationships read [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762937/whats-the-difference-between-identifying-and-non-identifying-relationships).