# Laravel Eloquent Update Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause'

Tags: php, sql-update, laravel

I never had any problems with Laravel but i ran into something what is really strange.

I have a `one to one` relation storing users metadata in a seperate table.

my Controller update looks like this

```
$val = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

        if($val->passes())
        {
            $this->cur_user->username             = Input::get('username');
            $this->cur_user->metadata->first_name = Input::get('first_name');
            $this->cur_user->metadata->last_name  = Input::get('last_name');
            $this->cur_user->metadata->gender     = Input::get('gender');
            $this->cur_user->metadata->location   = Input::get('location');
            $this->cur_user->email                = Input::get('email');
            $this->cur_user->metadata->dob        = Input::get('dob');
            $this->cur_user->metadata->about      = Input::get('about');

            if ($this->cur_user->save() && $this->cur_user->metadata->save()) 
            {
               $data = array('msg' => 'success');
            }
```

Relations

Users Model

```
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password');

    /**
     * Get the unique identifier for the user.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAuthIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    /**
     * Get the password for the user.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * Get the e-mail address where password reminders are sent.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getReminderEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }


    public function metadata()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('metadata');
    }


}
```

Metadata Model

```
class Metadata extends Eloquent {

    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $table = "users_metadata";

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('user');
    }
}
```

What is really weird, if i leave the $`this->cur_user->metadata->gender     = Input::get('gender');`and `$this->cur_user->metadata->about      = Input::get('about');` in my validation i get the following error

```
{"error":{"type":"Exception","message":"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL: update `users_metadata` set `gender` = ?, `about` = ? where `id` is null) (Bindings: array (\n  0 => '1',\n  1 => 'testing one 2 3',\n))","file":"C:\\BitNami\\apache2\\htdocs\\laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Connection.php","line":555}}
```

If i comment it out, all fine and works well, checked everything i do not see any strange things.

Could please someone give me a hint? (searched around found some answers but not really for my problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like your `user_metadata` table does not contain a foreign key to the `users` table, which it is requiring to be able to connect a user and his/her metadata. It also looks like the column is expected to be named `id`.

It would be helpful if you could post your database structure, or even better: Your migration files. I could venture a suggestion though:

Provided that you have an auto incrementing `id` column in your `users` table, your `user_metadata` migration file could contain something like this:

```
$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
$table->primary('user_id');
$table->foreign('user_id')
    ->references('id')->on('users')
    ->onDelete('cascade');
```

Perhaps you are missing some parts in your setup?

In other words, `user_metadata.user_id` should be an [identifying foreign key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/762994/1034002), reflecting `users.id`. And when a user is deleted, his/her metadata should automatically be deleted too (unless you're using for instance MyISAM, which that does not support foreign key relations).

See also the manual for more info on Laravel/Eloquent foreign keys: http://four.laravel.com/docs/schema#foreign-keys

Comment: now i feel really dumb, maybe this is the result for coding late night, insted of $primaryKey i defined $key in the users_metadata model, ah man still thanks for the reply

Comment: Hehe, I know the feeling!

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add to this since I've run into this problem and couldn't find a solution.

updateOrCreate will try to find a record with the default `id` column.
However, if your table has a different primary key column instead of the default, you'll have to define the primary key column in your model file like so:

```
protected $primaryKey = '<your column name>'
```

Comment: Thanks! This fixed it for me. I was using "$table->id('asset_id');" in my migration file to create a primary key column named 'asset_id' (with no 'id' column), and createOrUpdate was working on the create part but on update it was failing because it was looking for the 'id' column. By specifying $primaryKey in the model per your code snippet, I fixed my problem.