# Performance difference between foreign key identifying and non-identifying relationships

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys

I was just adding some foreign keys to my database and usually all my foreign keys are non identifying as I have never bothered making them identifying as I never knew the difference and my databases always seemed to work well enough for me.

Now I have decided that I am going to make this database properly and was making the foreign keys identifying and non-identifying. I was curious is there any performance difference with them when doing Joins?

Thanks

Comment: Finally, this is the big question that really matters. So anybody?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there could be some performance benefit to joins by making a foreign key on an identifying relationship. But it depends on the query (as optimization methods always do).

For example, querying the books for a given author:

```
SELECT a.author_name, b.book_name
FROM Authors AS a
JOIN AuthorBooks AS ab ON a.author_id = ab.author_id
JOIN Books AS b ON b.book_id = ab.book_id
WHERE a.author_id = 12345;
```

In this case, we hope the join to AuthorBooks uses an index. Which index will it use? It depends on how we define the indexes in that table.

The two entity tables are pretty straightforward.

```
CREATE TABLE Authors (
  author_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  author_name VARCHAR(50)
);

CREATE TABLE Books (
  book_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  book_name VARCHAR(50)
);
```

But there are two common ways that developers design the many-to-many table. One has an auto-increment id for its primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE AuthorBooks (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  author_id INT NOT NULL,
  book_id INT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (author_id) REFERENCES Authors (author_id)
  FOREIGN KEY (book_id) REFERENCES Books (book_id)
);
```

The other does not have an id. The primary key is the combination of the two foreign keys, and this makes them both have an **identifying relationship** with their respective referenced entity tables.

```
CREATE TABLE AuthorBooks (
  author_id INT NOT NULL,
  book_id INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (author_id, book_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (author_id) REFERENCES Authors (author_id)
  FOREIGN KEY (book_id) REFERENCES Books (book_id)
);
```

What's the difference in terms of performance?

First of all, keep in mind how MySQL implements indexes for foreign keys: If there's no index, the foreign key will implicitly create one. If there's an index already on the column, the foreign key will use it. Even an index that includes the foreign key column as the left-most column, that can be used, and there is no need to create a new index for the foreign key.

In the first AuthorBooks table design, as MySQL does the join from Authors to AuthorBooks, it looks up an entry in the index for the author_id foreign key. But to perform the second join, that index entry has to fetch the row it references, to get the book_id value, which it then uses to join to the Books table. So the joins ultimately take an extra table lookup.

In the second AuthorBooks table design, the author_id is indexed by the PRIMARY KEY of the table. So as the join does a lookup to the author_id, it comes with access to the matching book_id, without an extra lookup to the table. The book_id can then be used for the second join. This eliminates a step for each row found by the query.

This turns out to be a great benefit for performance. I have optimized some queries simply by making a many-to-many table use a covering index like this—whether by using the primary key or creating an extra two-column index on the two foreign keys—and this resulted in up to six orders of magnitude improvement for performance.

Comment: Totally unrelated comment: I can't work out the answer for the following question and would be interested if you had any solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48857776/why-does-mysql-not-always-use-index-merge-here

Comment: Achievement unlocked?

Comment: I got "Revival" and if I get a few more upvotes, I'll get "Necromancer". :-)

Answer (score 2):

The answer by @billKarwin is really good. I would just add one observation.

Identifying and non-identifying relationships are logical constructs. They model the underlying business domain - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762937/whats-the-difference-between-identifying-and-non-identifying-relationships) (also answered by the ubiquitous @billKarwin). The reason to use logical constructs like this is to make the database easier to understand (and therefore maintain, extend, etc.). It's *not* to make your database "faster".

Comment: I agree with this!