# Can't there be a "nonidentifying" N:M relationship?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, erd

My database **ERM** (Entity Relationship Model) has a `TEACHER` entity type, which is related to the `SUBJECT_MODULE` entity type (since different modules in each subject are taught by different teachers, and for some modules, even different chapters in each module can be taught by different teachers) by a `TEACH` relationship type.

*It is a `N:M` relationship, since each teacher can teach numerous subject modules, and each module can be taught by several teachers.*

***But in my opinion not an identifying relationship because the subject module is not dependent on the teacher to be uniquely identified; Please say so if you disagree with this.***

But from [this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/visual-database-creation-with-mysql-workbench--net-10975) (although it just says,"Identifying relationships are typically used for the join tables created from a many-to-many relationship. "), and finding out that the ERD modelling tool of MySQL Workbench contains only one tool to model a M:N relationship, which is for "`identifying N:M relationship`", at least the tool tip says so...  **I wonder if an N:M relationship is always or is not always an identifying relationship.** Please clarify me on this. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Check answers to linked question, if it does help.. check [What's the difference between identifying and non-identifying relationships?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/762937/whats-the-difference-between-identifying-and-non-identifying-relationships) I believe it should.

Answer (score 2):

> I wonder if an N:M relationship is always or is not always an identifying relationship.

The M:N relationship itself is never "identifying" (or "non-identifying" for that matter), but can be comprised from identifying or non-identifying 1:N relationships.

This is not about identifying any of the endpoints (teacher and subject module), this is about identifying the **connection** between them. In this case, it looks that the combination of keys migrated from the endpoint tables identifies the connection (by being part of the connection's key):

[image]

So while M:N relationship itself is not "identifying", the 1:N relationships it is comprised from are.

*(The tool UI you quoted probably uses the term "identifying M:N" simply as a shorthand for the above.)*

---

That being said, you could have left the connection without a key on top of these migrated keys:

[image]

It would still technically be M:N, but would now allow duplicated connections (i.e. the same teacher connected to the same subject module more than once), in which case the 1:N relationships above would no longer be "identifying".