# Is Identifying / Non-Identifying Relationship the same as Mandatory / Optional Relationship?

Tags: mysql, erd, modality

Basically, what is the difference between Identification and Modality of a relationship?
If they are the same thing, why MySQL Workbench implements them separately?

Further Explanation:

I get that Identification of a relationship means that the foreign key in the referencing table can be NULL if the relationship is Non-Identifying and cannot be NULL otherwise; And MySQL Workbench implements this feature O.K.  Identifying relationships are represented by a bold line while Non-Identifying ones are symboled by dashed-lines.

I was sure until now that modality(Optional/Mandatory Relationship) is the same thing! But MySQL Workbench implements modality compeletely separately. And In ERD it is depicted by "O" or "I" near the Entity. It is shown [here](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-qF3Z_dKSlks/T7yyuLEQtaI/AAAAAAAAAMw/7gohcWLDHJU/s400/Capture.PNG).

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference between identifying and non-identifying relationships?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/762937/whats-the-difference-between-identifying-and-non-identifying-relationships)

Comment: I have read that already, and i see differences.

Comment: As a matter of fact, you do not (fully). Bill Karvin's (accepted) answer does answer your question.

Comment: Yes it is briefly said in the final line trivially. But for someone like me, unfamiliar with the difference, it was not enough. I understood it after reading the response here. And the fact that answer is mentioned somewhere else as extra info, does not make two questions 'duplicate'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

[Identifying/non-identifying relates to child keys.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762937/whats-the-difference-between-identifying-and-non-identifying-relationships)  In an identifying relationship, the child record can only exist if the parent record exists. It *identifies* the child record. An identifying relationship is mandatory in the child table - it forms (all or part of) the key for the child table.

A non-identifying relationship can still be mandatory or optional, it's just that the child record can exist independently from the foreign key.

Mandatory/optional just tells you whether or not the field must have a value.  This might be a foreign key field, but it doesn't have to be.  If it's mandatory but not a foreign key, you can put any value you wish into the column (as long as it meets the other constraints); it just can't be `null`.