# How to create a zero or one to many relationship in Mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

In a database that have Orders, Customers tables, i need the relation between these two tables to be zero or one to many relationship, simply because in my application, an order can exist without being assigned to a customer.

One first idea that comes to my mind is to make the foreign key nullable, this way when creating an order the foreign key can be null, but i don't know how to do so.
I'm working on a model so i can render it to my 'teacher', so i need to know how to do it using the EER diagram.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create your 1:n relationship as normal.  Then double click the table to bring up the details.  On your new FK field, uncheck the "NN" column.  Now your FK can be NULL.

Comment: No.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/762937/whats-the-difference-between-identifying-and-non-identifying-relationships

Comment: Could you please elaborate? It's ok if the answer is not enough, but a brief explanation can help to move forward with the mysql workbench question.

Answer (score 16):

Mandatory option in "Foreign Key" tab in "Relationship" tab appears to be the way to control optionality.

Answer (score 4):

Simply do it this way

- Right click on the relationship and click on "Edit Relationship"
- Switch to the "Foreign Key" tab by click on the tabs below the interface
- Under Reference table section, uncheck the checkbox labeled "Mandatory"

There you go.[image]