# MYSQL simple data modeling

Tags: mysql, sql, data-modeling

A faculty member can take multiple pieces of equipment of campus, and such equipment is specifically assigned to one person.

What would the entities in this data model look like and what would their relationship be?

Cheers

Comment: You say:1 Faculty member can "take" multiple piecess....and such equipment is specifically assigned to 1 person...What does this mean? Try to formulate the statement accurately because in modeling, accuracy is very important.

Answer (score 1):

You have a one-to-many (1:n) relationship between faculty (1) and equipment (n).

So, I'd imagine a Faculty table and an Equipment table would be needed. The primary key of each would be some kind of unique ID (auto-generated like AUTO_INCREMENT, or explicitly given).

Since the 1:n relationship is Faculty:Equipment, you'd have the Faculty.id ("id" being a made-up column name for the primary key) be referenced in your Equipment table.

Therefore, the **referential-relationship**/bridge/match between these two tables would be Faculty.id and Equipment.faculty_id ("faculty_id" being a made-up column name which represents the corresponding Faculty table's primary key):

`Faculty.id = Equipment.faculty_id`

Answer (score 0):

That's a classical 1:n relationship. Have one table for the faculty members, say `members` with an ID as PK and
another table with the `assets`. The assets have also an ID (which is irrelevant for this) and a FK, say `assigned_to`
which refers to the PK of the `members` table.

Comment: thanks for clearing that up! would that make it a 1:n identifying or non identifying then?

Comment: @JackH According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/762994/5830574) it would be an _identifying_ relationship.

Comment: Hmm. I re-read that post and now think it's just the other way round. Conclusion: I'm not sure. :-(

Comment: "A book belongs to an owner, and an owner can own multiple books. But the book can exist also without the owner and it can change the owner. The relationship between a book and an owner is a non-identifying relationship." Just read this and it leads me to believe it is non identifying. Equipment could exist without an owner

Answer (score 0):

If you ever want to know who check out what equipment over time, your design has to be a little more sophisticated. You need some sort of Equipment Checkout table in between to keep the history of pieces of equipment being checked out and checked back in. When a piece of equipment is being checked out by a faculty member, create the EquipmentCheckout record with pointers to the faculty member and the piece of equipment and the DateOut. Then, link the Equipment record to the EquipmentCheckout record. As long as the CheckoutId field is not null, nobody else can check out that piece of equipment. When the equipment is returned, edit the EquipmentCheckout record with the DateIn, and set the CheckoutId for that piece of equipment to null. Then, you will have a history of who checked out what.

[image: Entities]