# Non-Identifying Relationship vs Identifying Relationship in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Why in MySQL Workbench EER Diagram for Non-Identifying Relationship we have 1:1 and 1:N WHILE for Identifying Relationship we have 1:1 , 1:N and N:M ?

I mean is it something related to the theory of relational databases (in relationships) or it is something about how MySQL workbench is?

[image]

Comment: here are discussions on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/762937/whats-the-difference-between-identifying-and-non-identifying-relationships

Comment: thanx for your help