# Primarykey handling on n:m relationships with identifying parent relationship?

Tags: mysql, database-design, mysql-workbench, primary-key-design

Watch this example for an identifying relationship between project and bug:

[image: Example MySQL Workbench schema]

MySQL Workbench creates on identifying relationships not a single primarykey like `bug.id` for table `bug`. The primary key in this case consist of `bug.id` and `bug.project_id` beacause `project` is the identifying parent entity for `bug`.

If I make in this case a `n:m` table like `bug_has_media` there are also the primarykey field `bug_project_id` added with reason `project` has an `1:n identifying relationship` with `bug`. In this case MySQL Workbench create this `bug_project_id` field automatically. Is it possible to delete the `bug_project_id` field in `bug_has_media` if it's not necessary? Or what is the background and purpose for difference between identifying and non-identifying relationships in MySQL? I know what the meaning of these two relationships is. But not why MySQL Workbench in this situation creates primarykeys based on two fields, and add these two fields in all n:m relations.

Comment: `bug.project_id` should not be in the primary key. It should be a non-unique index.

Comment: It's normal for a foreign key to refer to the primary key of the referenced table. If you fix the primary key of `bug`, it should do the right thing in `bug_has_media`.

Comment: @Barmar But what is the reason on MySQL Workbench then to difference between identifying and non-identifying realtionships? Your suggestion was if I understand it correctly to make only non-identifying realtionships?

Comment: Sorry, I don't really know anything about MySQL Workbench, and don't really deal with formal models of databases; I had to look up what an identifying relationship is. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/762994/1491895) points out "it's common practice these days to create a pseudokey for a child table, but not make the foreign key to the parent part of the child's primary key. Formally, the "right" way to do this is to make the foreign key part of the child's primary key." That's what Workbench is doing.

Comment: I know this answer and see that before :). But with it it's not finally clear for me what is now the best-practise way to handle these cases with 1:n relationships. I know for n:m tables it is best-practise for handle it often with multiple primary key fields. But in reference to the answer: Is the common practice way the way to go or the formally right way? And you would agree, that it isn't correct to delete some unnecessary fields like bug_project_id if it's part of the multiple fields based primary key?