# One to one relationship creates two foreign keys in MySQL workbench data modelling diagram

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, mysql-workbench

I am doing data modelling on MySQL workbench.

I have three data entities:

1. `company`
2. `driver`
3. `car`

Relationship is, one company has many drivers, one car has two drivers (main driver and co-driver)

This is the data model I have so far (I only created one `driver` link to `car` in the picture):

[image]

As above image shows, I linked `company` to `driver` with *one-to-many* relationship. The tool automatically creates `company_id` foreign key in `driver` table as expected. No problem there.

Problem comes in the relationship between `driver` and `car` . In the picture, I only linked *one-to-one* relationship from `car` to `driver`, I expected the tool would create one `driver_id` foreign key, but the tool automatically creates **two** foreign keys: `driver_id` & `driver_company_id`.

(If I create another *one-to-one* relationship for co-driver from `car` to `driver`, the tool would again create two new foreign keys, which is not indicated in the picture)

Why is that? Why does the tool create the `driver_company_id` foreign key besides `driver_id` foreign key for an one-to-one relationship? What is the concept behind? What would be the difference if now I manually delete the `driver_company_id` foreign key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solid connector indicates an [identifying relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762937/whats-the-difference-between-identifying-and-non-identifying-relationships/762994#762994), which means `driver.company_id` must be part of a compound primary key.

Therefore the foreign key from `car` to `driver` has to reference a compound primary key, so it creates both columns.

If you want to do what I think you want to do, make both foreign key connectors use dashed lines, which indicates non-identifying relationships.

Comment: Am I correct that if I manually delete `driver_company_id` the tool created, the relationship would then be non-identifying, otherwise identifying ??? I would like to understand how does having the `driver_company_id` foreign key makes the differences between  car and driver in practice.

Comment: You can create any foreign keys you want. But you requested an identifying relationship (by using the solid connector), so Workbench's method of automatically creating columns for the FK decided to make both columns the PK. If you didn't want it to create an identifying relationship, then use a dashed line connector.

Comment: Is that an `Yes` answer to my question in my comment above yours?

Comment: I'm not sure what DDL Workbench will create if you create an identifying relationship, then delete one of the columns in it. I'm saying you should start over, and create the FK relationship types according to the way you intend them to work.

Comment: Thanks, I will do that.