# Relationship Error while creating relation in Power BI

Tags: database, datatables, powerbi, database-normalization, relation

I have been creating a relationship in Power BI. where i want to connect "distinct_id" with "distinct_id" But power bi did not allow me to create any type of relation. Like ( one to one, one to many etc). Power BI gives me an error : "The Relationship has cardinality Many-Many"

On the other hand i have created a relation with "distinct_id" on different tables.

Here is the image of error :

[image]

What Should i do ?

Thanks

Comment: PowerBI is Warning you that on either side of the both tables there are no distinct values for column distinct_id. In that case it will lead to many to many relationship scenario.Just to avoid that, ensure you have unique values in one of your tables(ideally it should be a dimension or master table).

Comment: @balaji what should i do in order to create relation between these two ?

Comment: You should have distinct values in one of your tables for the column: distinct_id.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between identifying and non-identifying relationships?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762937/whats-the-difference-between-identifying-and-non-identifying-relationships)