# Multivalued attributed of a weak entity from ER model to relational model

Tags: database-design, erd

I have to map an ER diagram to a relational diagram, but I struggle to map multivalued attributes of a weak entity. The problem is in this piece of my ER diagram:
[image]

`COURSE_MATERIAL` is a weak entity is defined by the two multivalued attributes URLs and Books. Since `COURSE_MATERIAL` has a total participation constraint, it takes as primary key the key of the strong entity `COURSE` (as foreign key). In general, if a strong entity has a multivalued attributes, a new table is created which contains the key of the strong entity and the multivalued attribute (they're defined as the primary key of the new table). In this case the multivalued attributes belong to a weak entity that doesn't have any primary key on its own. How can I create the two tables for `URLs` and `Books`? Will them take the `COURSE` key like `COURSE_MATERIAL` and the multivalued attribute as usual?

Comment: What is "a proper key"? What is an non-proper key? What about what "a key" is in your method? You were told to follow what reference & what method in it & do what in this case? How are you stuck doing that? What "rule of conversion"?--We are not reading your textbook & there are many methods. What did you learn that is relevant from other answered Q&A re DDL for weak entities & why is it not applicable? PS A weak entity by definition has an owing entity whose pk/id is implicitly if not explicitly part of the weak pk/id. So where are you stuck identifying the relevant entity & pks/ids?

Comment: Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] Reflect research in posts.

Comment: Googling 'site:stackoverflow.com what is the key of a weak entity before:2011' ... [What's the difference between identifying and non-identifying relationships?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/762994/3404097) etc etc

Comment: You didn't identify or quote your reference & definitions. (Or define terms & explain reasoning using them in the last version.) "Since COURSE_MATERIAL has a total participation constraint, it takes as primary key the key of the strong entity COURSE (as foreign key)." False. "a weak entity that doesn't have any primary key" No such thing. Why do you think these things? Again: Find & quote & use definitions of "total participation" & "weak entity". It's true entities in a 1:1 relationship can have the same key, but not because of totality. Every entity has a PK. Please ask 1 specific question.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) An ERD is an image of DDL/text. Please give a legend/key with a diagram. (There are MANY methods.)

Comment: Again: "A weak entity by definition has an owing entity whose pk/id is implicitly if not explicitly part of the weak pk/id." As my comment said, as your reference will say, ask the link I gave says, as other Q&A will say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's clarify the concept of a [weak entity](https://vertabelo.com/blog/chen-erd-notation/) in ERD:

> an entity that cannot be uniquely identified by its attributes **alone**. The existence of a weak entity is dependent upon another entity called the owner entity. The weak entity’s identifier is a combination of the identifier of the owner entity and the partial key of the weak entity.

So it doesn't mean that a weak entity has no primary key,  but that its primary key is a compound primary key, a part of it being a foreign key to the owning entity. In the case of a 1:1 it doesn't even have to be compound: the weak entity could just reuse the primary key of its owner, since there is no other element related to the same entity to differentiate with:

[image]

With this in mind, the problem becomes straightforward: you can just use your standard technique for multivalued attributes, and add one (or two, one for book and one for url) table that has a even more compound primary key which is made of the compound primary key that you'll define for `COURSE_MATERIAL`, and an additional attribute that allows to differentiate the multiple values.  If you'd transform your ERD, it would then look like:

[image]

If showing these additional tables as additional weak entities in your diagram, as above, you'd find that it would look more complex than necessary: if `COURSE_MATERIAL` only has these multi-valued attribute and these attributes are independent of each other, you could directly create two relationships of `COURSE` with two weak entities `URL`, and `BOOK`, keeping compound primary keys less complex (only two components, instead of two and three).  The simplified diagram would then look like:

[image]